# bootstrap on rails: changing from select to radio on a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5

**rails 6.0.3**

**bootstrap 5**

I'm sorry if there is a simple answer, or if it's not even possible to change the following:

I currently have a select dropdown on my form,

```
<div class="field mb-3">
  <%= form.label :Please_select_document_type %>
  <%= form.select(:priority, [['Critical'],['Moderate'], ['Low']], { :include_blank => '-- Select One --'  }, {class: "form-check"}) %>
</div>
```

[Drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvAVL.png)

I have written below a radio button with the three same priority levels. **How do I** get the radio button **to store the correct value to priority when it is selected**?

```
<%= form.label :priority %><br>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <%= form.radio_button :priority, 'Low', type: "radio", class: "form-check btn-check", name: "options-outlined", id: "success-outlined", autocomplete: "off", checked: true  %>
  <%= form.label :priority, class: "btn btn-outline-success", for: "success-outlined", value: "Low" %>
  <%= form.radio_button :priority, 'Moderate', type: "radio", class: "form-check btn-check", name: "options-outlined", id: "warning-outlined", autocomplete: "off" %>
  <%= form.label :priority, class: "btn btn-outline-warning", for: "warning-outlined", value: "Moderate" %>
  <%= form.radio_button :priority, 'Critical', type: "radio", class: "form-check btn-check", name: "options-outlined", id: "danger-outlined", autocomplete: "off" %>
  <%= form.label :priority, class: "btn btn-outline-danger", for: "danger-outlined", value: "Critical" %>
</div>
```

[Radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57E2K.png)

Answer (score 0):

The radio buttons should have the name `<obj>['priority']`. The code in the question does not work since it uses a different name for each radio button. Remove the `name` key from the `radio_button` method call and let Rails add it for you.

```
<%= form.radio_button :priority, 'Low', type: "radio", class: "form-check btn-check", id: "success-outlined", autocomplete: "off", checked: true  %>
<%= form.label :priority, class: "btn btn-outline-success", for: "success-outlined", value: "Low" %>
<%= form.radio_button :priority, 'Moderate', type: "radio", class: "form-check btn-check", id: "warning-outlined", autocomplete: "off" %>
<%= form.label :priority, class: "btn btn-outline-warning", for: "warning-outlined", value: "Moderate" %>
<%= form.radio_button :priority, 'Critical', type: "radio", class: "form-check btn-check", id: "danger-outlined", autocomplete: "off" %>
<%= form.label :priority, class: "btn btn-outline-danger", for: "danger-outlined", value: "Critical" %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly now